# Jasypt en/decrypt success production failure

Tags: spring-boot, encryption

I get "Failed to bind properties under 'server.ssl.key-store-password' to java.lang.String:" after processing the application.properties file with first below and running the sb app.  What am I doing wrong or can try?

> mvn jasypt:encrypt -Djasypt.encryptor.password="the password"

I independently confirmed the decryption successfully

> mvn jasypt:decrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password="the password"
> -Djasypt.plugin.value="cipherText"